shorten a URL in googlesheets with Apps Script?
I have a long URL for a google slide that is put into a calendar event. Everything works, but the long URL looks funky and I would like to be able to use a short URL that google sheets can generate on it's own, without needing another API other than Apps Script.

/*
* Calendar must be created in advance. 
* Once created go to Settings and scroll down to  Calender ID. 
* Copy and paste ID into <Calendar ID> cell of main worksheet
* Copy and paste the calendar name into <Calendar Name> cell of main worksheet
*/
function CreateManyEvents() {
//Retrieve information from the spreadsheet 
// Make the 3rd sheet active in the active spreadsheet.
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[2]);

// Call function BulkDeleteEventsDelete on any pre-existing events 
BulkDeleteEvents(spreadsheet)

//Retrieve the value of the calendar ID from the cell that it lives in.
//Call CalendarApp service to open the calendar
var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

var classes = spreadsheet.getRange("A3:F8").getValues();
for (x=0; x<classes.length; x++) {   
    var item = classes[x];
    
    var title = item[0];
    var startTime = item[1];
    var endTime = item[2];
    var session = item[3];
    var what = item[5] + '\r\n\n' + item[4];

    //create event with data selected
    eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime,{location: session,description: what});  
    
  }

}


So is there a way to shorten the URL, item[5], before joining it with the other item that will go in the calendar event description?
I've looked around and solutions all involve changing a setting in Tools that I don't have - all I've got is the Apps Script under Extensions - and/or using some 3rd party API.
I'm hoping for a solution that is 'in house' as it were. Even changing the URL to its IP address would be OK.

Are you open to use, for instance, tinyurl in your code?

that's 3rd party, isn't it? Anyhoo, Lucepall's solution was spot on!

you may try embedding your URL inside an a tag with a name you like and put the item[5] value inside the href attribute.
Screenshot
I've tried this and this is how it looks.
Screenshot Calendar Event
Code Example
Try to add html inside the description key like this.
{description: "<a href='www.google.com'>Link</a>"});


Wow, it never occurred to me to go back to good ol' HTML! Lovely!
